# right padded spaces are removed when stored in a variable in shell scripting

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting. I am struggling alot with this.

I did following :

```
tlswrk41> myvar=6042811103
tlswrk41> printf "%-25d" $myvar
6042811103               tlswrk41@illin2510!TLS:tlswrk41>
```

Meaning spaces are printed but when i store it in a variable, spaces are removed  (while below given left pad code works):

```
   tlswrk41> myvar=6042811103
   tlswrk41> myvar1=`printf "%-25d" $myvar`
   tlswrk41> tlswrk41> echo "$myvar1"
   6042811103
   tlswrk41>
```

-----Left pad------------

```
tlswrk41> myvar=6042811103strong text
tlswrk41> myvar1=`printf "%25d" $myvar`
tlswrk41> echo "$myvar1"
           6042811103
tlswrk41>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf -v`:

```
myvar="6042811103"
printf -v myvar1 "%25d" "$myvar"
echo "[$myvar1]"
[               6042811103]
```

OR:

```
printf -v myvar1 "%-25d" "$myvar"
echo "[$myvar1]"
[6042811103               ]
```

I used `[` and `]` to show preceded and following spaces.

---

**EDIT:** if `printf -v` isn't supported then use:

```
myvar1=$(printf "%-25d" "$myvar")
```

Comment: When i used it i got error :                                                               a.sh[50]: printf: -v: unknown option
Usage: printf [ options ] format [string ...]

Comment: That means your BASH has older `printf`. Check my edited answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the easiest method :

typeset. For above : `typeset -L25 myvar="6042811103";`

-L -> it will add spaces at the end of variable
-R -> it will add spaces at the start of the variable